# React Native Woocommerce API fails when parameters are set

Tags: react-native, woocommerce

I recently decided to give React Native a shot. I am running into some trouble communicative with Woocommerce using the `react-native-woocommerce-api`.

When I get all the products, it works great, but when I try to set an attribute to the HTTP call, it fails.

This works:

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Loading products...");
    Woocommerce.get("products", {}).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

This doesn't (**per_page added**):

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Loading products...");
    Woocommerce.get("products", {per_page: 3}).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Error thrown:

```
Object {
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
    "data": Object {
        "status": 401,
    },
    "message": "Invalid signature - the signature doesn't match.",
}
```

HTTP request that works:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=###&oauth_nonce=###&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1560818379&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=###=&
```

HTTP request that doesn't work:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products?oauth_consumer_key=###&oauth_nonce=###&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256&oauth_timestamp=1560817909&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=###=&per_page=3
```

I should also add that when adding `per_page=3` using Postman, it works. I don't know what difference it makes, the HTTP calls are very similar, it seems that only the uri parameters order are different.

Any help is appreciated! Been stuck on this the whole freaking day. :/

Comment: I should have written the solution for this when it was fresh, sorry, i think my problem was the URL encoding, nothing major.

Answer (score 1):

Open **react-native-woocommerce-api.js** in **node_modules\react-native-woocommerce-api\lib\**

then goto line 195 (_getOAuth().authorize function) and change:

```
params.qs = this._getOAuth().authorize({
  url: url,
  method: method
});
```

to

```
params.qs = this._getOAuth().authorize({
  url: url + '?' + this.join(data, '&'),
  method: method
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be marked as the correct answer. I have been stuck in this issue for days